# Multiple monitor performance on external docking station

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, docking-station

I have a [Lenovo T400](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/landing_pages/thinkpad/t400s) and [Toshiba Dynadock](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001H9O73O).  I just bought a [Dell Ultrasharp U2412M](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=320-2676&~ck=baynoteSearch&baynote_bnrank=1&baynote_irrank=0) for it and it seems that there is a little bit of a lag in rendering. I want to add another 24 inch monitor to it but I'm worried that my configuration will not work for two monitors and the rendering will be slow.

Do I need some kind of a graphics card adapter so that both monitors will run smoothly?

Comment: What kind of graphics card is in the laptop?

Comment: Intel GMA 4500MHD Dynamic Video Memory Technology 5.0